# Find difference between row elements in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm new to this page and new to programming as well.
Let me pose my problem.
I have an array let's say

```
1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9 

3 2 1
```

what I want to do is calculate for each row the difference between all elements.

```
{Math.Abs(1-2)=1

Math.Abs (2-3)=1

Math.Abs (1-3)=2}
```

for the first row. Next I want to find the average for each row(in first (1+1+2)/3) and finally keep the row with the smallest average value.

What is the most efficient way to do it??(I was thinking that perphaps LINQ could work but I don't know how to properly use LINQ).
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you all in advance!!!!

EDIT:
Thank you all for the answers...there are really usefull and helped me understand the way I should process my problem. I see that most all of you have recommended the use of List. So that raises another problem for me (remember little programming knowledge) how can I convert an int[,] array to List, is this is possible?? Should I convert int[,] to int[][] first and then to List ?
For one more time thank you for your answers and your time.

I created the following function for converting the 2d array to a List..but it seems that it's not working properly..Any help would be truly appreciated..

```
 public static List<int[]> GetMyNumbers(int[,] result)
    {

        int[,] res = result;

        int length = res.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
        int width = res.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;
        int[] rows = new int[width];
        List<int[]> numberArrays = new List<int[]>();

        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length / width; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < width; k++)
            {
                rows[k] = res[i, k];
                Console.Write(rows[k]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            numberArrays.Add(rows);//this doesn't fill the list properly..It adds to all list items the last row of the 2d array

        }

        return numberArrays;


    }
```

Comment: If you are discarding all the other rows other than the one with the lowest average, do you need to calculate the differences for them? If not, the efficient way is to discard the rows first and then work out the differences for the 1 row you have left, as the differences will be more time consuming than the averages (or at least, depending on how many items is in a row that is).

Comment: may i didn't pose my question clear enough. what i want to do is calculate the average of the differences for each line..

Comment: @tasos ok so am I understanding you correctly that you just want to go through each row, calculate the difference then find the average difference of each row?

Comment: @Purplegoldfish yes that's exactly what i want to do..calculate the difference between all row elements and then find the average difference..

Comment: is there always 3 elements in a row?

Comment: no that's just an example we don't know in advance the length of the array..

Comment: If the three elements are [`x1`, `x2`, `x3`] then the average of [`x1`-`x2`, `x2`-`x3`, `x1`-`x3`] is always `2/3*(x1-x3)`. Did you mean to take the average of the absolute difference instead?

Comment: Please also include how the array is defined? Is it a `2D` array (`A[i,j]`), or a jagged array (`A[i][j]`).

Comment: I mean to take the absolute difference and the array is A[i,j] not a jagged..thanks for your time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for basically.  No I did not test the code to make sure that it is 100% correct, but should get you moving in the right direction at very least.

```
  // Look, a two dimensional version.
  int[][] numberArray = GetMyNumbers();

  // Placeholder for the lowest averge / corresponding index.
  double lowestAvg = double.MaxValue;
  int lowestIndex = -1;

  for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numberArray.Length; rowIndex++)
  {

    {
      int[] row = numberArray[rowIndex];
      int n = row.Length;
      int[] diffs = new int[(n * n) - n];

      // Get all of the differences.
      int count = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
          diffs[count] = Math.Abs(row[i] - row[j]);
          count++;
        }
      }

      // Average them..
      double sum = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < diffs.Length; i++)
      {
        sum += diffs[i];
      }
      double avg = sum / diffs.Length;

      // Compare to the lowest value, making note of a new low.
      if (avg < lowestAvg)
      {
        lowestAvg = avg;
        lowestIndex = rowIndex;
      }
    }

  }

  // Now that we are here, we know which index has the lowest average of differences.
  // Do whatever you want with it.
  int[] TheAnswer = numberArray[lowestIndex];
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer.. but how can i convert int[,] array to List<int []>?? beacause .ToList method doesn't work or Cast.ToList...

Comment: There, now it uses a 2D array.

Answer (score 2):

It's extremely crude, but hopefully you can take from this. Basically, it converts your jagged array into a List of arrays and then works out the average in a seperate method, and orders the results by average and takes one.

Worth noting that my solution always tries to store the positive value of a difference (as that seems to be what you were doing), i.e. instead of 1 and 3 giving -2 it gives 2.

I am convinced there is a cleaner way to create this solution but this is the best I could come up with for now.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[][] multi = new int[3][];
            multi[0] = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
            multi[1] = new int[3] { 5, 10, 20 };
            multi[2] = new int[3] { 3, 4, 8 };
            List<int[]> t = multi.ToList();
            List<int[]> avg = t.OrderBy(x => GetAvgDifference(x)).Take(1).ToList();
        }

        public static double GetAvgDifference(int[] arr)
        {
            List<int> differences = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i; j < arr.Length; j++)
                {
                    int difference = arr[i] - arr[j];

                    if (difference < 1)
                    {
                        differences.Add(difference * -1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        differences.Add(difference);
                    }
                }
            }

            return differences.Average();
        }
```

Comment: I'm trying to work through all the solutions given here and since I'm newbie I have questions. If I understood well your solution you propose to pass the values into a jagged array and then convert it to list and process the list instead. My problem is that the array is the output of another function and i don't know in advance the size of the array. I've tried to find through the net what can i do to convert int[ , ] array to List<int[]> but i didn't find something that worked..have you any suggestion??

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ like this on an array with only one row :

```
int[] tab = { 1, 2, 3 };
var tuples = tab.Select((number, index) => new Tuple<int, int>(index, number));
var average = tuples.SelectMany(t => tuples.Where(current => current.Item1 > t.Item1), (t1, t2) => Math.Abs(t1.Item2 - t2.Item2)).Average();
```

You have just to apply the same to all the rows of your array, and then use the Min() extension method.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to solve this I would change the way your data is stored.

First I would create a new class called myNumbers (or whatever), this class has to contain an array of integer and a property called average with a get method only (you dont want to be able to manually change this value. You can also create a constructor that accepts an array of integer to be used when you create new instances of the class. (this new class represents 1 row in the array you currently have)

Your property called average is going to be an int, it will loop through the array and calculate the average then return it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470(v=vs.71).aspx C# properties tutorial.

Now in your main code you want to get rid of the array, make a List instead and populate it with new instances of your myNumbers class.

Now all you have to do is create a for each loop and go through the list, you can check the average property of each item in the list to get the average value OR you could ignore the loop altogether and use LINQ to select the highest value

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383799(v=vs.90).aspx Linq tutorial (there are plenty more on the net)

I think the above aproach would suit your needs best as you need to store the averages etc. It also gives you some practice with classes / properties / loops / Lists etc as you are new to programming.

If you have a go at some code and still struggle please update your post here and we will try to help. I thought I would answer this without code first so at least you can have a go at doing it yourself etc.

Comment: @tasos good luck!  When you get it finished post your code and im sure people will be willing to suggest improvements etc :) And welcome to SO

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
    var rows = new List<List<int>>(){
            new List<int>(){1, 2, 3},
            new List<int>(){4, 5, 6},
            new List<int>(){7, 8, 9},
            new List<int>(){3, 2, 1}};

    var averages = new List<double>();
    foreach(var list in rows)
    {
        var diffs = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)
            for (int j = i+1; j < list.Count; j++)
                diffs.Add(Math.Abs(list[i]-list[j]));
        averages.Add(diffs.Average());
    }
    averages.ForEach(i=>Console.WriteLine(i));
    Console.WriteLine("Minimum average is " + averages.Min());
```

All your sequences are differ in a similar way so in this example all averages will be 1.3333

Answer (score 1):

If performance really matters consider using a flat int array for
storing your rows (you don't have the memory overhead of a `List<int>`). 
Then iterate over the flat array by incrementing
your current index by the row length and then calculate the average for
the current row.

Here is a small example:

```
int rowLen = 3;
int numberOfRows = 3;
int[] rowValues = new int[rowLen * numberOfRows];

float[] avgs = new float[numberOfRows];

// First row
rowValues[0] = 1;
rowValues[1] = 2;
rowValues[2] = 3;

// Second row
rowValues[3] = 6;
rowValues[4] = 5;
rowValues[5] = 6;

// Third row
rowValues[6] = 7;
rowValues[7] = 8;
rowValues[8] = 9;

float currMinAvg = float.MaxValue;
int minIdx = -1;
int currRow = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfRows * rowLen - rowLen; i += rowLen)
{    
  avgs[currRow] = 0;
  int c = 0;
  for (int k = i; k < i + rowLen-1; k++)
  {
    for (int p = k + 1; p < i + rowLen; p++)
    {
      c++;
      //Console.Out.WriteLine("calc: rowValues[{0}] - rowValues[{1}]", k, p);
      avgs[currRow] += Math.Abs(rowValues[k] - rowValues[p]);
    }
  }

  //Console.Out.WriteLine(avgs[currRow]);
  avgs[currRow] /= c;

  if (avgs[currRow] < currMinAvg)
  {
    minIdx = i;
    currMinAvg = avgs[currRow];
  }
  currRow++;
}

Console.Out.WriteLine("Min row indexs: {0}, min average = {1}", minIdx, currMinAvg);
```

Note, the code above is optimized for performance. It clearly **hurts readability**.

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code with a few comments where I do weird stuff.  I think you already have a lot of interesting answers but I didn't see anything that's just plain simple, so here's my attempt.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // quickest way to initialize your input
    var input = new int[][]{
        new int[]{1, 2, 3},
        new int[]{4, 5, 6},
        new int[]{7, 8, 9},
        new int[]{3, 2, 1}
    };

    /* to get the average,
     * 1. add up all the differences
     * 2. divide by m choose 2 where m is the length of a row
     */

    // helpful factorial functoid
    Func<int, int> factorial = null;
    factorial = (n => (n > 1) ? n * factorial(n - 1) : 1);
    var mChoose2 = factorial(input[0].Length) / (2 * factorial(input[0].Length - 2));

    var getAverageOfDifferencesFunctoid = new Func<int[], double>(
        row => row.Select(
            (number1, indexInRow1) => row.Select(
                (number2, indexInRow2) => indexInRow2 > indexInRow1 ? Math.Abs(number1 - number2) : 0
                // add up all the differences for number1 with the rest of the array
            ).Sum()
        // add up all the sums of all the differences
        ).Sum()
        // divide by the number of differences
        / (double)mChoose2
    );

    // use the functoid defined above to calculate the average of differences for each row and pick the minimum
    Console.WriteLine(input.Select(row => getAverageOfDifferencesFunctoid(row)).Min());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double[,] A = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } , { ... } ... };
// Initialize array of averages
double[] R = new double[N] // N is number of rows
// Calculate averages for each row
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    R[i] = (Math.Abs(A[i,0]-A[i,1])+Math.Abs(A[i,1]-A[i,2])+Math.Abs(A[i,2]-A[i,0]))/3;
}
// Find the best value
double R_min = R.Max();
// Find the index where values equals the min.
int k = R.Select((r, i) => r == R_min ? i : N).Min();
// Now A[k,*] contains the values you want to keep.
```

Comment: thank you very much for your solution..but the array I posted was an example unfortunately I don't know in advance the number of columns or rows of the array A[i,j]. So I'm looking for something that will work for different sizes of array. but thanks again..

Comment: then use `N = A.GetLength(0)` to find the number of rows.